# What's the meaning of "You verminate the sheet of your birth"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, obscure-terms

What's the meaning of "You verminate the sheet of your birth"?

Does it have a figurative meaning?

What is "the sheet of your birth" referring to? Any guess?

**I really hate the way everyone thinks it is a Pinter's play so the words are meaningless! The words, phrases, and sentences might be odd and uncommon, but I'm sure they're not utterly meaningless!**

The immediate context:

> GOLDBERG: No society would touch you. Not even a building society.
>   MCCANN: You're a traitor to the cloth.
>   GOLDBERG: What do you use for pyjamas?
>   STANLEY: Nothing.
>   GOLDBERG: **You verminate the sheet of your birth.**
>   MCCANN: What about the Albigensenist Heresy?
>   GOLDBERG: Who watered the wicket in Melbourne?
>   MCCANN: What about the blessed Oliver Plunkett?
>   GOLDBERG: Speak up Webber. Why did the chicken cross the road?

From [Harold Pinter's play *The Birthday Party*](https://books.google.com/books?id=nKCtne2rH9wC&lpg=PA438&ots=gKZHlzxpZe&dq=%22You%20verminate%20the%20sheet%20of%20your%20birth%22&pg=PA438#v=onepage&q=%22You%20verminate%20the%20sheet%20of%20your%20birth%22&f=false); more complete context available via Google Books.

Comment: Context might be necessary, because in modern English, this means little - *verminate* is an archaic word meaning to infect with vermin, and I'm not sure what *the sheet of your birth* would be - perhaps *placenta*, but that doesn't make a lot of sense either.  It seems insulting, but highly archaic.

Comment: The Birthday Party By Harold Pinter. It may mean something like 'you tarnish your own name', 'tarnishing your own reputation' etc.

Comment: The context may not have helped you, but it will for someone else. Did you look up the term "verminate" what did you find?

Comment: Perhaps  the bedsheet upon which 'he' was born @jimmackenzie?

Comment: The whole page that the sentence appears on (in *The Birthday Party* by Harold Pinter)   is close to nonsense. That context *is* helpful.

Comment: Context is _always_ a major part of _any_ meaning. And if that context "doesn't help much" because you keep trying to see meaning in individual lines in absurdist plays, then maybe that same context should be a hint as to why that specific definite meaning escapes you...

Comment: The context is essential. Goldberg and McCann are harassing Stanley with rapid-fire unanswerable questions, some of which are deliberately meaningless.

Comment: Okay, Okay, got it. The context is important. But what can you get from the sentence when you first see it out of the context?

Comment: What @oerkelens said. In the *specific* context, I'd say the fact that it's from an archetypal example of [‘theatre of the absurd’](https://natashaob.wordpress.com/literature/harold-pinters-play-the-birthday-party/) is in fact the *primary* context. It seems unlikely anyone else would have used the  expression before Pinter, and I suspect he didn't care much about it having any *precise* meaning (is it a more literal reference to defiling one's biological mother's honour, or a more metaphorical reference to the land of one's birth? A "eupemistic" reference to urinating? Who cares?).

Comment: *"What's the meaning of "You verminate the sheet of your birth"?"* __ looking at the 2 sentences immediately preceding it, I strongly suspect that 'using nothing for pyjamas' has very much to do with 'verminate the sheet' and the author was being discreetly and ironically obscene @A playgoer. 'Why did the chicken cross the road' probably signifies that the questions are essentially irrelevant here.

Comment: verminate
[vur-muh-neyt]
*verb*

   -- to become infested with vermin, especially parasitic vermin.

    Archaic: to breed or infest with vermin. Source: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/verminate The same meaning is given at https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/verminate

Comment: It's Pinter.  It's nonsense.

Comment: I think this is a reasonable question to ask, and a reasonable answer is condensed entirely into @HotLicks comment. Of course there is _some_ sense to the phrase, but mostly in its poetic absurdity.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about interpreting a literary passage.

Comment: Clare, this is not an interpretation of a literary passage! I just asked to know the meaning of a sentence in a literary work, not to get different interpretations of the whole work!!!

Comment: @playgoer you have asked: *Does it have a figurative meaning?* The only way to answer that is to examine the context. Since the context is literature not day-to-day language, that calls for interpretation of literature . Not the whole work, but the place of the sentence within it.

Comment: @Clare good point. The meaning of the sentence is dependent on its literary context. But then I think that's a reasonable answer to an on-topic question. To give the literary interpretation as answer might be too off-topic  though.

Comment: The thing I dislike about Pintor is how absurdly literal his writing is. It's like reading a technical manual for using a toaster.

Comment: @Clare I agree with you regarding the sheet of the bed on which he was born (hence the upvote). I read that meaning into it but also thought that it might be an Irish (or possibly Catholic) condemnation meaning that the person brings dishonour to his family. If so it goes nicely wth the line about Plunkett.

Answer (score 3):

The literal meaning of the phrase seems reasonably straightforward. Samuel Johnson, [*A Dictionary of the English Language*](https://books.google.com/books?id=kyRWAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT596&dq=bow+and+scrape&hl=en&sa=X&ei=T0X-VMyMPJLuoAT1vYBA&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBzge#v=onepage&q=%22to%20breed%20vermine%22&f=false), volume 2 (1756) offers this brief entry for *verminate*:

> To VERMINATE. v. n. {from *vermin*} To breed vermine.

And "sheet of your birth" seems most likely to refer to the sheet on the bed where the birth of the person being addressed took place. A somewhat similar expression appears in [*Snow* v. *Snow*](https://books.google.com/books?id=BHoDAAAAQAAJ&pg=PR2&dq=bed+%22sheet+of%22+birth&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdrNDizLLXAhVBx2MKHZFkCGQQ6AEISjAG#v=onepage&q=bed%20%22sheet%20of%22%20birth&f=false) (March 16, 1842), in *Notes of Cases in the Ecclesiastical & Maritime Courts*, volume 2 (1844):

> [Article] 11 [of "a suit for separation, by reason of cruelty"]. That, in the end of June, 1835, a third child was born, Mr. S. being absent, and upon his return, three or four days after, when he entered his wife's bed-room, she was sitting up in bed, supported by pillows, engaged in writing a note, and "Mr. S., seeing a spot of ink on **the sheet of her bed**, flew into a passion and struck her in the head," and that such his conduct threw her into a state of fever.

Putting the two notions together, we get this approximate the meaning:

> You breed vermin in [or infest with vermin] the bedsheets where you were born.

Comment: I don't see how the second passage has anything to do with the topic.

Comment: @HotLicks: It shows use of "the sheet of [one's] bed" to refer to bedclothes, which is rather unusual, I think. Further, this was the bed in which Mrs. Snow had three or four days earlier had given birth. That's the best I can do for a close match to "the sheet of [one's] birth," Perhaps it isn't good enough?